# PHP preg_match_all not working on own server but does on PHP Sandbox

Tags: php, regex, version, preg-match-all

The following code snippet is not working on the server of my hostprovider, but it is on the PHP Sandbox (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/(<!--(?:(?!-->).)*-->)|(\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).|[\n\r])*\*\/)/", 'sa fsaf safasa sa sa sasa sa as<!--<option value="fr" >FR</option>-->sfafsfsaf asf s f', $comments); 
print_r($comments);
?>
```

Could anybody think of a reason, why this does not work?

My PHP Settings: PHP 5.6

Thanks

Result on PHP Sandbox:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => <!--<option value="fr" >FR</option>--> ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => <!--<option value="fr" >FR</option>--> ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => ) 
)
```

Result on my server:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => ) 
)
```

Comment: It does work. The problem is probably that you try to see your result in your browser (that obviously doesn't display html comments). So, right click and choose something like "source code of the page", to see the expected result in the code.

Comment: damn, I feel so stupid :/ Thank you!

Comment: Don't, it's a common mistake.